# RuntimeError: doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS - Django

Tags: django

The folder organization is like this:

```
/project/
         apps/
              app1/
              app2/
              ...........
         core/
               view.py
              ............
         __init__.py
         manage.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
```

But I get an error when I want to import a model "House" that I have in the folder "app2" to view.py, the import is the following "from apps.app2 import House" and the error I get is this: House does not declare an explicit app_label and is not in an app in INSTALLED_APPS.
If you can help me with a solution, thanks in advance.

The "INSTALLED_APPS" structure is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "core",
    "apps.app1",
    "apps.app2",
    "tailwind",
    "theme",
]
```

the module I am using is views.py which is located in the "core" app, which is the following:

```
from apps.app1.models import House
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.views import View


clase HouseView(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        
        contexto = {
            
        }
        return render(request, "pages/index.html",context)
```

Comment: Well, have you added the app hosting the model to `INSTALLED_APPS` like the error message tells you?

Comment: @AKX yes, that's right

Comment: Can you show your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Can you also show the actual module (`.py` file) structure you're using, too?

Comment: @AKX If you have already added it, please update the information.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app1 and app2 folders, find an `apps.py` file. Inside, there will an `AppConfig`. Change `name=apps.app1`. Similarly, for app2, `name=apps.app2`.

Then inside your INSTALLED_APPS, add your app like `apps.app2` or `apps.app1`